# issues with resource.designer after upgrade to mvvmcross 4.1

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have an xamarin android project using mvvmcross. with version 4.0 it worked without issues. After the upgrade I'm no longer able to build and get a lot of these errors:

```
error CS0117: 'Resource.Styleable' does not contain a definition for 'Theme_toolbarStyle'
```

if it helps, here is the link to the repository: https://github.com/NPadrutt/MoneyFox.Windows/tree/xamarin

EDIT: I found that it this error seems to be linked to the mvvmcross support design package. When I deinstall it, it will build (but then I have an inflate exception..)

How can I fix that?

Comment: Find out which package causes this.

Comment: It seems to me it is the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Design When I remove it, the issue is gone. But the app will crash on startup due to an inflation error then.

Comment: Make sure you have the latest Android SDK - API 23. You can install it from the Android SDK manager

Comment: Checked that. There was an update, but the issue still persists.

Comment: Try doing a clean solution and rebuild.

Comment: Tried to whole spectrum of reinstall, delete packages, restart vs, delete obj and bin folders, clean and rebuild.. Unfortunately didn't work..

Comment: Turns out it's a combination. When I update the Xamarin Android Support there will be over 100 errors. Also when I update the MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Design I get 2 errors. when I just don't update these it seems to work..